# How can store text and then search for it using Python

Tags: python

**I am making a program that takes a screenshot of a word, then translates that picture into text. I want to store that text somewhere. However, everytime get a new word to add, i want to check to see if that word is already present in the File/list/(whatever you think is the correct data storage). *Now that the aim of the prgram is explained, I will detail the issue. The code doesn't recognise that new item added to the list is already in the list. It should print a 1 if present and a 2 if not, the code only ever prints a 2* **

```py
import easyocr
import pyautogui
import time
import cv2 
import numpy as np
reader = easyocr.Reader(['en'])
tag = 1
while True: 
    time.sleep(3)
    image = pyautogui.screenshot(region=(670,400,550,130))
    image = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(image),
                     cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
    tag+=1

    img = cv2.imwrite(f"img/image{tag}.png", image)
    file_name = f"img/image{tag}.png"

    results = reader.readtext(file_name)

    text=""
    for result in results:
        text += result[1] + " "
        text =  text.strip("")

    """my_list =  [text]
    for item in my_list:
        if item == text:
            print("1")
    print("2")"""

    file_object = open("wordlist.txt", "a")
    text = text.strip(" ")
    file_object.write(f'"{text}",')
    file_object.close()

    List = open("wordlist.txt").readlines()
    My_List = [List]
    print(List)

    for item in List:
        if item == text:
            print("1")
    print("2")
```

Comment: Don't you append an additional comma when you write to file_object?

Answer (score 2):

Does it not always print 2 because it's after the loop. I mean that when the loop is done it will print 2 even though it found the text or not. I usually make a boolean and if I found the text piece I make it true and else I make it false. Then I just check after the loop whether the boolean is true or false.

```
foundtext = False;
for item in List:
    if item == text:
        foundtext = True
        
if foundtext == True:
    print(1)
else:
    print(2)
```

But I don't know why it doesn't print 1.

Comment: A very good point! Can you fix the indentations in your example, please? As it stands, an error would be thrown.

Comment: Sure. Hate these indentations.